# Using redux in react.js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

I'm trying to go by the following guide:

https://www.tutorialspoint.com/redux/redux_react_example.htm

I was having a few errors which I got rid of by removing the .css files it was trying to import and making it a bit clearer. Then, I got the error `ReferenceError: window is not defined`. I added

```
if (typeof window === 'undefined') {
    global.window = {};
}
```

at the top of my file and that seemed to get rid of the issue, so I did the same with global.document. I was getting the same error for document. Now, I'm getting `TypeError: document.getElementById is not a function`. My file (index.js file) is below:

```
import React from 'react'
import { render } from 'react-dom'
import { Provider } from 'react-redux'
import { createStore } from 'redux';
import reducer from '../src/reducer/index'
import App from '../src/App'


if (typeof window === 'undefined') {
    global.window = {};
}

if (typeof window === 'undefined') {
    global.document = {};
}

const store = createStore(
   reducer,
   window.__REDUX_DEVTOOLS_EXTENSION__ && 
   window.__REDUX_DEVTOOLS_EXTENSION__()
)
render(
   <Provider store = {store}>
      <App />
   </Provider>, document.getElementById('root')
)
```

I'm not sure what I need to do to get rid of the error, `TypeError: document.getElementById is not a function`.

Edit: package.json

```
{
  "name": "website",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "next dev",
    "build": "next build",
    "start": "next start"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@zeit/next-sass": "^1.0.1",
    "babel-preset-es2015": "^6.24.1",
    "bluebird": "^3.7.2",
    "bootstrap": "^4.5.3",
    "cors": "^2.8.5",
    "create-react-class": "^15.7.0",
    "express": "^4.17.1",
    "isomorphic-fetch": "^2.2.1",
    "next": "^9.5.5",
    "pg": "^8.5.1",
    "react": "^16.14.0",
    "react-bootstrap": "^1.4.3",
    "react-dom": "^16.14.0",
    "react-redux": "^7.2.2",
    "react-table": "^7.6.2",
    "redux": "^4.0.5",
    "sass": "^1.32.2"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "devDependencies": {
    "redux-devtools": "^3.7.0",
    "redux-devtools-extension": "^2.13.8"
  },
  "repository": {
    "type": "git",
    "url": "git+https://github.com/astoryumw/website.git"
  },
  "bugs": {
    "url": "https://github.com/astoryumw/website/issues"
  },
  "homepage": "https://github.com/astoryumw/website#readme",
  "description": ""
}
```

Comment: where are you seeing these errors? how are you running this Javascript file?

Comment: `Server Error
TypeError: document.getElementById is not a function

This error happened while generating the page. Any console logs will be displayed in the terminal window.` From my terminal: `TypeError: document.getElementById is not a function
    at eval (webpack-internal:///./handle_redux/src/index.js:45:15)
    at Module../handle_redux/src/index.js (/Users/Austin/website/.next/server/pages/index.js:187:1)
    at __webpack_require__ (/Users/Austin/website/.next/server/pages/index.js:23:31)` I'll add my package.json above

Comment: Running with npm run dev

Comment: Can you also post your working example repo?

Comment: This isn't working, but I'll post what I have publicly on github

Comment: Yep I meant minimal reproducible repo

Comment: https://github.com/astoryumw/redux/tree/main/handle_redux note: I had this in another file with a working program. I'm experimenting with how I can use redux to handle something, so I was trying to build a basic redux program.

Comment: This looks like unrelated with redux but it's related to nextjs though

Comment: How can you tell?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/227269/discussion-between-tmhao2005-and-austin-story).

Comment: I've checked your repo. But I'm not sure how could you run it since it looks like you missed to create `pages` dir which requires for nextjs